# I got 2 scenes that i want to render

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, compositing-nodes

I got 2 scenes that i want to render. One scene where the world background is opaque and one where its transparent.

I am currently rendering but i only see one scene being rendered. Is this normal? I have connected everything right in the compositor

[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Community I need to know wether both scenes are rendering. And how i can see that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hopefully i did understand your right, so you wanna do this?

[image]

Use the alpha over node to render the one layer "over" the other and with the background of the first layer.

Comment: yes, thank you so much :)

Comment: You are welcome!